# Setting a gradient background color for surfaceview

Tags: android, android-layout

At the moment i have a static plain blue background color on my surfaceview, I wanted to know a way to get a blue gradient from deep blue to light blue vertically. Currently I set the background color like this

```
         canvas.drawRGB(15,03,175);
```

Any tips or advice will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can get help from here :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936803/how-to-draw-a-smooth-dithered-gradient-on-a-canvas-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer in the form of paint's set shader, this works nicely for the moment

```
         Paint gradPaint = new Paint();
         gradPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0,0,0,getHeight(),Color.BLUE,Color.CYAN,Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
         canvas.drawPaint(gradPaint);
         //Where getHeight() is the height of the canvas
```